# Three.JS render .stp file

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, 3d

I am looking to create a simple 3d Model preview based on a '.stp' file.

While searching I found the [Three JS](https://threejs.org/) libairy. This libairy allows you to render 3D files like this example: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_3mf

I would love to implement this into my own site except with a .stp file (The file: https://www.eleq.com/binaries/downloads/ELEQ%20LS-94%203D%20solid.stp).

I have tried to load this file with the `THREE.ObjectLoader` without a success. The loader expects a JSON format.

```js
// Create a scene
var scene = new THREE.Scene(); 
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000); 
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(); renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight); 
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
        
// Load the object
var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
loader.load(
  // resource URL
  'https://www.eleq.com/binaries/downloads/ELEQ%20LS-94%203D%20solid.stp',
  
  // called when resource is loaded
  function ( gltf  ) {
    scene.add( gltf.scene );
  },
  
  // called when loading is in progresses
  function ( xhr ) {
    console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );
  },
  
  // called when loading has errors
  function ( error ) {
     console.log( 'An error happened' );
  }
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My first three.js app</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Does someone have expirence with 3D model rendering that can help me?

Comment: They say ["no"](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/is-there-any-way-to-load-step-file-using-three-js/2842), but that's a bit old by now. Have you tried to search for a Loader?

Comment: I have searched for hours but I am not able to find anything. Does someone has a suggestion?

Comment: On the page I linked, is a link to step2stl converter, can't you use that?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I'm not able to find the link you're talking about. Can you re-link the URL down below?

Comment: ??? https://3dmeshviewer.github.io/stepfileviewer/

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have to convert the file to the gltf format so It can be loaded and displayed

You can check this thread from the official three.js forums

https://discourse.threejs.org/t/is-there-any-way-to-load-step-file-using-three-js/2842/5

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35737642)